# d3js type of the scale and axis of the rendered chart based on DOM

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to implement d3 zoom behavior on top of the existing library. This is my zoom behavior:

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .x(x)
    .scaleExtent([1, 10])
    .on("zoom", zoomed); 


function zoomed() {
     svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
}
```

And the problem is that **x scale and xAxis are in the source code**, that I don't want to change. Is there any way to know the ***type of the scale and axis *based on the DOM*?***

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by type of scale ?

Comment: Quantitative, Ordinal..

Comment: Not sure how do you plan to use the category of the scale but if you looking to update it then setting the domain with the new bunch of values, the axisi gets updated automatically.